# How to do package ordering with testng?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I have few test cases which are in different packages, and I want them to run in some specific order. Following is my *testng.xml*

```
<test name="x-tests" preserve-order="true" parallel="false">
        <packages>
            <package name="org.analytics.integration.tests.cappdeployer"/>
            <package name="org.analytics.integration.tests.analytics"/>
            <package name="org.analytics.integration.tests.loganalyzer"/>
        </packages>
</test>
```

But I have noticed these packages are not executed in order. With a bit of googling I have noticed that `preserve-order=true` works only with classes. So if I am to execute these tests in order, the only way to go is with class tags with the order I need?

Is there any good way to sort out this issue?

Comment: Why do the tests need to be ordered?

Comment: because i need am doing a configuration change using the test case in the first package, which should be applicable to all other tests in all other packages.

Comment: I dont think its a good idea to create tests which are dependent on ordering. Each specific unit/integration test should be isolated from each other to prevent various kinds of issues.

Comment: These are integration tests. In that case is it valid to do this?

Comment: Why don't you consider doing the setup in one of the many annotations given by testng say BeforeSuite or any of the listeners.